# Can anyone explain the working of this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

```
for j in range(1,11):
    print([f"{j}even", f"{j}odd"][j%2==0])
```

```
//Output
1even
2odd
3even
4odd
5even
6odd
7even
8odd
9even
10odd
```

But when print statement is modified to:

```
    print([j%2==0][f"{j}even", f"{j}odd"])
```

then the output is a TypeError. Why?

Comment: The first case, you have a list of 2 strings, and you are indexing them with j%2==0, the second case is broken because you have a list of 1 bool and you are indexing it with 2 strings, which is not possible. Note that booleans are ints in python. So j%2==0 is either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this code below, shall explain the code snippet (above):

```
for j in range(1,11):
    i=j%2
    print([f"{j}even", f"{j}odd"][i])
```